# MVC 4 master page _Layout pass data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a masterpage called `_Layout.cshtml` and placed in the folder `Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`. 
I created a controller: `SharedController.cs` to pass data to `_Layout.cshtml` 
but does not enter into the controller. 
How can I pass data to each load masterpage `_Layout.cshtml`?

This is the controller for example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace HAnnoZero.Controllers
{
    public class SharedController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult _Layout()
        {
            ViewBag.help = "ciao";
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do _Layout is ,master page i don't think that you can do something this way

Comment: In the master page I have a menu, in this menu I want to insert labels that show the methods count from db

Comment: Use viewbag in the action or write code in master layout

Comment: I would not recommend the use of viewbag as it is not strongly typed.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad can you make me some sample code request in master db layout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, don't call it a master page. That's from Web Forms. In MVC, `_Layout.cshtml` is a "layout". That may seem like semantics, but it's important to differentiate because in Web Forms, the master page is a true page in it's own right, with it's own code behind. In MVC, a layout is only an HTML template with some placeholders. The controller, and specifically the action of the controller that was requested, is solely responsible for the page context. That also means you can't have a `_Layout` action that adds context to the layout because that action is not being called, and even if you did (by going to a URL like `/Shared/_Layout` in your browser, it would fail when loading `_Layout.cshtml` as a view, because it needs a superficial view to fill in the call to `@RenderBody()`.

If you want to render something with its own context in your layout, then you must use child actions:

**Controller**

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Something()
{
    // retrieve a model, either by instantiating a class, querying a database, etc.
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

**Something.cshtml**

```
@model Namespace.To.ModelClass

<!-- HTML that utilizes data from the model -->
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@Html.Action("Something", "ControllerSomethingActionIsIn")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is creating a common base controller that other controllers inherit from:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.Title = "Hello world";
    }
}

public class SharedController : BaseController
{
    ...
}
```

Then in _layout you just use:

```
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
```

Answer (score 0):

Layout pages do not work this way.  The view returned by your action is rendered within a `_Layout` page when using a default MVC project.

See [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3) for more of an introduction to `_Layout` pages.

One way to display information in a `_Layout` page is to use a [child action](http://theshravan.net/blog/child-action-methods-in-asp-net-mvc/) method which is called from the `_Layout` page.

For example, the _Layout.cshtml may contain a call similar to:

```
@Html.Action("GetNews", "Home", new { category = "Sports"})
```

And then you would have a controller action similar to:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult GetNews(string category)
{
    ....
}
```